# Linq query with grouping and Max date

Tags: c#, linq

```
class ProductVersion
{
   string ProductId
   string VersionNumber
   VersionType versionType
   DateTime ReleaseDate
}
```

So i need to get List from collection of ProductVersions with lastest ReleaseDate grouped by ProductId and VersionType.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an anonymous type for the group:

```
var prodVersionList = AllProductVersions
    .GroupBy(pv => new { pv.ProductId, pv.versionType })
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(pv => pv.ReleaseDate).First())
    .ToList();
```

You have to make `ProductVersion`'s properties and fields `public`, otherwise you can't access them.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = productVersions
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductId, x.versionType })
    .Select(x => new { x.Key.ProductId, x.Key.versionType, LatestReleaseDate = x.Max(y => y.ReleaseDate) })
    .ToList();
```